# Filter Datagrid onLoad

Tags: datagrid, filter, dojo

My data grid successfully filters when I select a month from a dropdown list, however when I try to filter it onLoad it just doesn't filter. The dropdown successfully displays the current month, and the grid should also show the current month data.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
        dojo.require("dojox.data.XmlStore");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
        dojo.require("dojo.date");

        theMonth = new Date();

        dojo.addOnLoad(function()
            {
                dojo.byId('monthInput').value = month_name[(theMonth.getMonth()+1)];
                var filterString='{month: "' + theMonth.getMonth() + '"}';
                var filterObject=eval('('+filterString+')');
                dijit.byId("eventGrid").filter(filterObject);
            }
        );

        var eventStore = new dojox.data.XmlStore({url: "events.xml", rootItem: "event", keyAttribute: "dateSort"});

        function monthClick() { 
            var ctr, test, rtrn;

            test = dojo.byId('monthInput').value;

            for (ctr=0;ctr<=11;ctr++)
            {
                if (test==month_name[ctr])
                {
                    rtrn = ctr;
                }
            }

            var filterString='{month: "' + rtrn + '"}';
            var filterObject=eval('('+filterString+')');

            eventGrid.setQuery(filterObject);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
   <div id="header" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" class="pfga"></div>
   <div id="menu" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" class="pfga"></div>

   <div id="content" style="width:750px; overflow:visible" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" class="pfga">
        <div dojotype="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" url="months.json" jsID="monthStore"></div>

        <div id="pagehead" class="Heading1" >Upcoming Events</div>
        <p>
        <input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="monthStore" searchAttr="month" name="id" id="monthInput" class="pfga" onChange="monthClick()" />
        </p>
        <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="eventStore" class="pfga" style="height:500px; width:698px" clientSort="true" jsID="eventGrid">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th field="date" width="80px">Date</th>
              <th field="description" width="600px">Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th field="time" colspan="2">Details</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>

   </div>     

   <div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

filter() is client side filtering. It should be called after the grid is built and data loaded.

You want to set the query parameter of the grid. This determines what records from the store get to the grid. Its similar to "select * from table".

Filter is used to filter these results, so call filter when the user makes a selection from your client side filtering. Filter is similar to adding a where clause to "select * from table".

Comment: Yes, the grid is built and the data is loaded when I try to use client side filtering and it simply didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an asynchronous issue. That is, your addOnLoad executes because the DOM is loaded, but your data hasn't finished loading. Can you try connecting your month filtering logic to the following instead of to addOnLoad? Maybe it could look something like this:

```
 dojo.connect(eventGrid, "_onFetchComplete", function(){
                dojo.byId('monthInput').value = month_name[(theMonth.getMonth()+1)];
                var filterString='{month: "' + theMonth.getMonth() + '"}';
                var filterObject=eval('('+filterString+')');
                dijit.byId("eventGrid").filter(filterObject);
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I tried it but it didn't work. When I have this in the addOnLoad the part that sets the monthInput dropdown list does set the dropdown to the current month. This code doesn't even do that. 

So far I have a workaround in that on load it just displays all the data and I've added a month column. When a user clicks on the dropdown and it sorts it also hides the month column.